# Creating a ScrollView with a sticky top tab navigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello I am trying to create a component in my app that looks really similar to [this](https://youtube.com/shorts/HUUfkqioT_8?feature=share). I am currently struggling with how to make it so that i can have a collapsible header that scrolls seamlessly through both the header and the nested tabs scrollviews.

Here's what i [have so far](https://youtube.com/shorts/hOqlRcN0ULc). As you can see, the scrollview is causing both the header and the content area to scroll at the same time. I was wondering if there was a way to make the header scroll first (when at the top) and then the content area scrolling after.

Here is my code
Header with tabs Render in parent:

```
<Animated.View 
  style={[styles.headerScrollableContainerContent, {
    top: headerHeight
  }]} 
>
   <View>
      {...header content}
   </View
   {TabRender()}
</Animated.View>
```

Header height calculation:

```
const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
const headerHeight = scrollY.interpolate({
   inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
   outputRange: [HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT, HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
   extrapolate: 'clamp',
});
```

About Tab:

```
<ScrollView
  style={styles.container}
  onScroll={Animated.event(
    [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: props.scrollY}}}],
    {useNativeDriver: false}
  )}
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
>
   {...Scroll content}
</ScrollView>
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas or suggestions. Any help would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [this](https://medium.com/@linjunghsuan/implementing-a-collapsible-header-with-react-native-tab-view-24f15a685e07) Medium article. It was really helpful and I would highly recommend checking it out if your stuck